# how to fix "Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled."

Tags: java, spring, api, maven, intellij-idea

I'm getting this error when trying to run my Java code with Maven using Intellij:

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.

2022-06-29 23:39:33.179 ERROR 4068 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.server.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>RestAPI</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <!--> mysql on my computer version, the version should be true<-->
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.26</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

RestApi.java

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class RestApiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RestApiApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

User.java

```
package com.server.app.rest.Models;

import javax.persistence.*;
// mysql columns, connection
@Entity
public class User {
    // id is primary key
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @Column
    private String firstName;
    @Column
    private String lastName;
    @Column
    private String job;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getJob() {
        return job;
    }

    public void setJob(String job) {
        this.job = job;
    }
}
```

UserRepo.java

```
import com.server.app.rest.Models.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

//userrepo get features from jpa.
public interface UserRepo extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
}
```

properies

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/crudusers?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false

spring.datasource.username=username

spring.datasource.password=password

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

ApiControllers.java

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class ApiControllers {
    // first connect the page, except this- / - get error
    @GetMapping(value = "/")
    public String getPage(){

        return "Welcome";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally i solved the problem. The problem was the wrong password. I wrote the right password, then fixed the error.

Comment: accept the solution as the answer, you will see the check or good button under the vote buttons.